# Resource file for additional language

Tags: c#, localization, resources

How i can add resource for additional language, under existing resource file?

See picture from Solution explorer:

[image]

If I try add new one I get this:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to create a new one? Like fr but then i.e. nl? Or is the fr one not working?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What happens when you try to add another file (say `Error.ru.resx`)? Also, please explain what you _expect_ to happen.

Comment: I want add new one like Error.de.resx. And i want that, new resource will be under Error.resx, like other ones (cs, fr)

Comment: And? What happens what you try that?

Comment: @oded I uploaded the result, check new image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding a resource file, Visual Studio will add it at the folder level, as you have seen.

In order for you to get it displayed as a sub-node, you will need to edit the `.csproj` file directly (you can right click the project, select "Unload Project" then right click again and select "Edit .csproj" - when done, reload the project via the right click. Alternatively, open the `.csproj` file in any text editor).

You will an entries like this:

```
<Compile Include="Error.cs.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Error.cs.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Error.cs.resx">
```

You will need to change this to:

```
<Compile Include="Error.cs.resx">
  <DependentUpon>Error.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Error.cs.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Error.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

This will put both `Error.cs.resx` and `Error.cs.Designer.cs` under the `Error.resx` node.

There is no way to directly do this in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement that the other language recourse files are under the current one?
Else you could create something like this:

[image: Translations]

This will automatically be picked up for translations.

.cs isn't a translated file, it's the classfile supporting the resx file.

Comment: You got the .cs thing wrong, I'm afraid. "cs" is the ISO 639-1 code for the Czech language. Translations.cs.resx would be valid.

Comment: @Flo I dond't think you understood my answer correctly. I meant the file extension .cs, not the language cs.

Comment: Fair enough. The hint comes a bit out of the blue, though, since the .cs files weren't explicitly mentioned anywhere before.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer is fully correct, there is a better/faster/nicer way. There exists an extension with the name [File Nesting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting) which will make this job much easier.